# Laravel Nova - Hide view & edit from BelongsToMany field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-nova

The relationship between model `Question` & `Choice` is Many to Many.

`Nova/Question` :

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ...
        BelongsToMany::make('Choices')
    ]
}
```

Which displays below screen

[image]

I would like to hide view & edit option from the view. Allowing user only to attach/ detach the choice.

I tried creating `QuestionPolicy` with below method which didn't work. If I use `ChoicePolicy`'s `update` & `create` method it will hide view & edit option from `Choice` resource.

```
public function updateChoice(User $user, Question $question)
{
    return false;
}
```

How can I achieve hiding view & edit option from relationship ?

**Update**

`Question` model

```
class Question extends Model
{
    ...
    /**
     * The choices that belong to the question.
     */
    public function choices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Choice');
    }
}
```

`Choice` model

```
class Choice extends Model
{
    /**
     * The questions that belong to the choice.
     */
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your models

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta Updated the question with models

Comment: and what is in your controller code

Comment: Doesn't have controller for these models. I have Laravel nova `resources`

Comment: I'm in the same case with a pivot table. Have you found how to do it ? Thanks

Comment: @Fab Nope, couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your QuestionPolicy define

```
public function attachChoice(User $user, Question $question, Choice $choice)
{
   return ! $question->choices->contains($choice);
}
```

Taken from this [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1003#issuecomment-497008278), take a look for more detail

Answer (score 0):

you could return this in your policy and same goes to your update

```
 public function view(User $user, Survey $survey)
 {
     return false
 }
```

Comment: This will hide view option from `choice` resource as well. I only want to hide it in under `question` resource

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to put the code below in your QuestionPolicy :

```
public function attachAnyChoice()
{
   return false;
}
```

Hope this help.
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/authorization.html#authorizing-attaching-detaching

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help you

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
     return [
        ...
        BelongsToMany::make('Choices')->except('edit','view');
     ]
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. `Method Laravel\Nova\Fields\BelongsToMany::except does not exist.`.

Comment: for which user you want to hide view and edit options

Comment: For all the users I want to hide the view & edit options

Comment: Have you put `use Laravel\Nova\Fields\BelongsToMany;` at the top of your file?